# prevent loading JQuery more than once

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-mobile, struts2-jquery

I'm new to JQuery-Mobile.

I have created a master page in which i have included few links of jquery mobile script and css. 
In master page I'm loading another page into a selected div using ajax but script of master page is not accessible in loaded page. so i need to load again script in loaded page.

This increase load time, can anyone help me out to resolve this.

Any suggetion will be helpful, Thanks.

**Edited**

Master Page code. In this page there is a div having Id=>"mainContent". In this div i'm trying to load my another page on click of anchor having id "link1" or "link2".

on click of link1 i'm calling ajax and on click of link2 loading on given target.

in both case it works fine if all script is included in loaded page.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjm" uri="/struts-jquery-mobile-tags" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1 , maximum-scale=1">

<script src="../resources/template/js/base/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="../resources/jquery.window.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/jquery.windowAlt.js"></script>
 <script src="../resources/template/js/base/jquery.ui.core.min.js?s2j=3.3.3" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../resources/template/js/plugins/jquery.subscribe.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="../resources/template/js/struts2/jquery.struts2-3.3.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        jQuery.struts2_jquery.version = "3.3.3";
        jQuery.scriptPath = "../resources/template/";
        jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
        jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache : false});
        jQuery.struts2_jquery.require("js/struts2/jquery.ui.struts2-3.3.3.min.js");
    }); 
 </script>
 <link type="text/css" href="../resources/template/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css?s2j=3.3.3" rel="stylesheet" id="jquery_theme_link">
<script src="../resources/template/js/plugins/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/template/js/struts2/jquery.mobile.struts2-3.3.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/template/js/plugins/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />

<title>IDP-Dashboards</title>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" >
 function pageRefresh() {
     location.reload(); //Reload the current page.
 }
 $(document).ready(function(){
     if ($('body').find('[data-role="header"]').width()<400) {
     $('#home_img').attr('src','../resources/img/icon_home_small.png');
        $('#logout_img').attr('src','../resources/img/icon_logout_small.png');
     }
     $(window).on('resize',function() {
     if ($('body').find('[data-role="header"]').width()<400) {
        $('#home_img').attr('src','../resources/img/icon_home_small.png');
        $('#logout_img').attr('src','../resources/img/icon_logout_small.png');
    }else{
        $('#home_img').attr('src','../resources/img/icon_home.png');
        $('#logout_img').attr('src','../resources/img/icon_logout.png');
    }
     });
 });


 $(document).on('click', '#link1', function(){
     alert("here...");
     $.ajax({
            async : false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: "./getMobileDashboard",
            data : {
                //"mode" : "viewUserThumbnails",
        },
            success : function (msg) {
                 $("#mainContent").html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
</SCRIPT>
<link href="../resources/css/ApplicationStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css">
</head>
<body id="body">
<div data-role="page" id="dashboardPage">

    <div style="width: 100%">       
    <%-- <sj:a button="true" id="link1" href="getMobileDashboard" targets="mainContent" style="float:right;">Dashboards</sj:a> --%>
    <%-- <sj:a button="true" id="link1" href="#" onclick="test();" >Dashboards</sj:a> --%>
    <sj:a button="true" id="link1" href="#" >Dashboards</sj:a>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 100%">
    <sj:a button="true" id="link2" href="getMobileDynamicForms" targets="mainContent" style="float:left;">Forms</sj:a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content"  id="mainContent" style="padding: 0px;">   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is sample page which i'm loading on click of link1 to div having is "maincontent"

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjm" uri="/struts-jquery-mobile-tags"%>

<%-- <script src="../resources/template/js/base/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="../resources/jquery.window.css"rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/jquery.windowAlt.js"></script>
<script src="../resources/template/js/base/jquery.ui.core.min.js?s2j=3.3.3" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../resources/template/js/plugins/jquery.subscribe.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script  src="../resources/template/js/struts2/jquery.struts2-3.3.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        jQuery.struts2_jquery.version = "3.3.3";
        jQuery.scriptPath = "../resources/template/";
        jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
        jQuery.ajaxSetup({
            cache : false
        });
        jQuery.struts2_jquery
                .require("js/struts2/jquery.ui.struts2-3.3.3.min.js");

    });
</script>
<link type="text/css"
    href="../resources/template/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css?s2j=3.3.3"
    rel="stylesheet" id="jquery_theme_link">
<link type="text/css" href="../resources/complex/css/complex.css"
    rel="stylesheet" id="jquery_theme_link">
<link type="text/css" href="../resources/jquery.window.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../resources/complex/js/layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../resources/complex/js/complex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../resources/complex/js/layoutui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/jquery.windowAlt.js"></script>

<link href="../resources/css/front.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../resources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css">
<link href="../resources/css/elements.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css">
<link href="../resources/css/extended.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css">
<link href="../resources/css/setup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../resources/css/dStandard.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css">

<script
    src="../resources/template/js/plugins/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="../resources/template/js/struts2/jquery.mobile.struts2-3.3.3.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="../resources/template/js/plugins/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" /> --%>


<style>
 .box { position: relative; float: left;  }
</style>
<link href="../resources/css/ApplicationStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css">
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <div id="dashboardContainer" >
            <s:iterator value="dashboardprivilege">
                <div class="box" align="center">
                    <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="javascript:void(0)"
                        onclick="viewDashboards('<s:property value="id" />','<s:property value="title" />','<s:property value="dashboardType"/>');"
                        rel="external">
                            <img src="../niv-images/<s:property value="imageName" />" width="200px;"
                                height="150px"><div style="width:210px;padding-top: 5px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;"><span>
                                <s:property value="title" />
                                </span></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </s:iterator>
            <s:iterator value="dashboards">
                <div class="box" align="center">
                    <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="viewDashboards('<s:property value="id" />','<s:property value="title" />','<s:property value="dashboardType"/>');"  rel="external">
                    <img src="../niv-images/<s:property value="imageName" />" width="200px;" height="150px">
                    <div style="width:210px;padding-top: 5px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;"><span> <s:property value="title" /> </span></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </s:iterator>
            <span class="stretch"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('pageshow', '#dashboardPage', function(){

            });

    function serchDashboard() {
        var searchFile = $('#searchFiles').val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "mobileSearchView?searchFiles=" + searchFile,
            success : function(result) {
                $('#data').html(result);
            }
        });
    }

    function viewDashboards(id, title,dType) {
        if(dType == '3') {
            url = "viewPortlet?id="+ encodeURIComponent(id) ;
        }else {
            url = "processjstree?id=" + encodeURIComponent(id) + "&mode="+ encodeURIComponent("loadViewSWF");
        } 
        winOpen(url, title);
        return false;
    }

    function winOpen(link, t) {
        var sw = window.screen.availWidth;
        var nsw = sw - 50;
        link += "&screenWidth=" + nsw;
        $.window({
            title : t,
            url : link,
            showModal : true,
            modalOpacity : 0.5,
            maximizable : false,
            createRandomOffset : {
                x : 200,
                y : 150
            },
            bookmarkable : false,
            onShow : function(wnd) {
            }
        });
    }

    function pageRefresh() {
        location.reload(); //Reload the current page.
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $width3 = $('#dashboardContainer').width();
        $(".box").css("width",220+((((($width3/220)%1)*220))/Math.floor($width3/220)));


        $(window).on('resize',function() {
            $width2 = $('#dashboardContainer').width();
            $(".box").css("width",220+((((($width2/220)%1)*220))/Math.floor($width2/220)));
                }).resize();
    })
</SCRIPT>
```

Page is loading but all content is not loading properly....

Comment: Can you please add your code for better understanding?

Comment: If you're doing things right, the worst-case scenario is that you'd be loading a cached version of jQuery, which takes very little time. Are you certain that (a) you're set up to cache jQuery correctly, and (b) "double-loading" of jQuery is the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can always check if jQuery has already been loaded with:

```
if (typeof(jQuery) !== 'function') {
// add script tag here with ref to jquery
}
```

Also i think frameworks like requireJS handles this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Better create ajax call as a json request

Then handle the required javascript functionality after the response from ajax in parent page itself.

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType:'json',
                    url:  url+'ajax.php',
                    data: {name:value},
                    beforeSend : function(){

                 }
                 })
                .done(function(data)
                {

                    //Here you will results like below
                    //data.html
                    //data.status
                    if(data.status == true)
                    // your required operation
                    // here html and status are the variables set in json encoded array.

                });
```

in ajax.php

```
<?php
// do your php operation and set the result to a variable $result

echo json_encode('html'=>$result,'status'=>true); 
// you can set any number items in array , so that in parent window you can easily handle these items.

 ?>
```

Comment: can you show me any example to do so... see in my code of master page i'm calling ajax. It is working fine if all script is included in loaded page but if i comment script it is not working fine..

Comment: Added an example in above comment with json method..@amitkumar12788